# How to code iterator for a bag? (inner class required)

Tags: java, dictionary, project, computer-science

im having problems with my project and im asked to make a iterator over the elements of a bag and that i needed to use a inner class to define my iterator for densebag

This is what ive got so far, im not sure if the other methods work correctly but here goes(see link, having trouble pasting code in here, first timer =( )

```
public class DenseBag<T> extends AbstractCollection<T> {

    private Map<T, Integer> denseBagMap;
    private int size;  // Total number of elements in the bag
    transient int modCount;




    public DenseBag() { //DONE!
            size = 0;
            denseBagMap = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
    }

    public String toString() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THIS!");  
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {//DONE!
            if (o == this) {
                    return true;
            }
            if (!(o instanceof DenseBag)) {
                    return false;
            }
            DenseBag<T> dense = (DenseBag<T>) o;
            return size == dense.size;
    }

    public int hashCode() {//DONE!
            return this.denseBagMap.hashCode();
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THIS!");
    }

    public Set<T> uniqueElements() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THIS!");
    }

    public int getCount(Object o) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("YOU MUST IMPLEMENT THIS!");
    }

    public T choose(Random r) {//DONE!
            ArrayList<T> keyArrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
            int index = 0;
            Iterator<T> it = denseBagMap.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){
                    T current = it.next();
                    while (index < denseBagMap.get(current)){
                            keyArrayList.add(current);
                            index++;
                    }
                    index = 0;
            }

            return keyArrayList.get(r.nextInt(keyArrayList.size())); }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {//DONE!
            return denseBagMap.containsKey(o);
    }

    public boolean add(T o) {//DONE!
            if (denseBagMap.containsKey(o)) {
                    denseBagMap.put(o, denseBagMap.get(o) + 1);
            } else {
                    denseBagMap.put(o, 1);
            }
            return true;
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {//DONE!
            if (o != null){
                    if (denseBagMap.containsKey(o)){
                            Integer newValue = denseBagMap.get(o)-1;
                            denseBagMap.put((T)o, newValue);
                            return true;
                    }
            }
            return false;
    }

    public int size() {//DONE?
            return size;
    }
```

}

*** I managed to work on this basing on the initial comments and heres what i got: ***

```
private final class DenseBagIterator<E> implements Iterator<T> {
    private Iterator<Entry<T, Integer>> entrySetIterator;
    private int count = 0;
    private int max = 0;
    private T current = null;
    private int expectedModCount;

    public DenseBagIterator() {
        entrySetIterator =  denseBagMap.entrySet().iterator();
        expectedModCount = modCount;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (count < max) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return entrySetIterator.hasNext();
        }
    }

    public T next() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        if (count < max) {
            count++;
        } else {
            Entry<T, Integer> entrySet = entrySetIterator.next();
            current = entrySet.getKey();
            max = entrySet.getValue();
            count = 1;
        }
        return current;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if (current == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        if (max > 1) {
            DenseBag.this.remove(current);
            count--;
        } else {
            entrySetIterator.remove();
            size--;
        }
        max--;
        expectedModCount = modCount;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're having?

Comment: Well, what do iterators do? Essentially, it provides a convenient interface to loop through your desneBagMap. So what you need to do is write an iterator class that implements Iterator and gives back your key/value tuples from your map in .next().

Comment: @Jaynathan: No, that's not what an iterator for a Bag<T> should do. It should return instances of T, and should return exactly the elements that are stored in the bag. Not the key/value pairs.

Comment: oh, that's true, i was only looking at the map >_<

Comment: edited the iterator/inner class part a bit, what do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to write your iterator for you. But the basic idea is:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new DenseBagIterator();
}

private class DenseBagIterator implements Iterator<T> {
    // your implementation of the Iterator interface methods goes here
}
```

Your private inner class has access to all the private data and the methods of the DenseBag object for which it was created (using `DenseBag.this.whatever`, if necessary), and it can maintain its own state data as well (so you can have several iterators going in parallel).

Start coding all the required methods and ask when you get stuck on something specific. :)

Comment: ok i managed to do this, im really confused now: *see edit on main post

Comment: @user2263743 - Okay, I see the code. You don't indicate if there's still a problem. Is it working?